# Sampling from intersection of sphere and simplex

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I need to isotropically sample vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$ of Euclidean norm $c$ such that components are positive and add up to 1. Any suggestions how to do this in Mathematica?

For $d=3$ this means sampling from one of the circular contours in

```
SliceContourPlot3D[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 
 x + y + z == 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Things I tried

1. `RandomPoint[ RegionIntersection[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .9],  Simplex[IdentityMatrix[3]]]]` -- returns unevaluated
2. Rejection [sampling](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-alternating-projections.nb). Inefficient for $d=3$, completely impractical for higher values, I need $d=100$.

Code below is for debugging rejection sampling in $d=3$ case. It takes a sample of 3d points, projects onto $x_1+x_2+x_3=1$ plane, displays them along with the target region marked in gray. Will appreciate any suggestions on making an efficient sampler.

[image]

```
(* simplex visualization code from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139443/217 *)
visualize[points_, c_] := Module[{},
   d = 3;
   kk = Array[k, 6];
   mat = Partition[kk, 2];
   bb = Array[b, 3];
   source = {{-1/Sqrt[2], 0}, {1/Sqrt[2], 0}, {0, Sqrt[3/2]}};
   target = IdentityMatrix[3];
   eqs = Table[mat . source[[i]] + bb == target[[i]], {i, 3}]; 
   sol = First@Solve[eqs, kk~Join~bb];
   {mat0, bb0} = {mat, bb} /. sol;
   imat0 = PseudoInverse[mat0];
   unmap[point_] := imat0 . (point - bb0);
   expr = mat0 . {x, y} + bb0;
   reg = ImplicitRegion[Reduce[Thread[expr > 0]], {x, y}];
   
   regionPlot = RegionPlot[reg, PlotStyle -> None];
   pointsPlot = ListPlot[unmap /@ points];
   val = Sqrt[Total[expr^2]];
   contourPlot = 
    ContourPlot[val == c, {x, y} \[Element] reg, 
     AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 10, 
     ContourShading -> None, 
     ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.3], Gray, Thickness[.02]]];
   
   Show[regionPlot, contourPlot, pointsPlot]
   ];

points = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {100, 3}];
visualize[points, .8]
```

**Motivation** is to get a diverse sampling of discrete distributions of given complexity. JimB's previous [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/250124/217) achieves some progress for the case when entropy is the complexity measure. This question corresponds to [linear entropy](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/linear-entropy) as the complexity measure. Related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4533715/998) on math.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Ball` & `InfinitePlane` instead of `Sphere` & `Simplex` in your first approach:

```
reg=DiscretizeRegion@  RegionIntersection[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, .9], InfinitePlane[IdentityMatrix[3]]]
p=RandomPoint[reg , 100];
Show[Region[reg], Graphics3D[Point[p]]]
```

[image]

Comment: I think OP wants to choose the norm of the points sampled, hence the `Sphere` instead of `Ball` in the question

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks for your hint. That means radius of the sphere is randomly too?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Radius of the sphere is fixed to some user-provided value $c$. With a couple of tweaks (use difference of 2 balls to simulate the sphere) this gives an [alternative implementation](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/2e25ad9e-bb43-48c8-997f-261b33617938) of rejection sampling. However, too inefficient to use for higher values of $d$

Answer (score 2):

First two remarks:

- The intersection between the simplex given by $x_1 + \ldots + x_d = 1$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_d \geq 0$ and the sphere $(x_1)^2 + \ldots + (x_d)^2 = c^2$ is nonempty if and only if $1/\sqrt{d} \leq c \leq 1$.
- If $1/\sqrt{2} < c < 1$, which seems to be of interest to OP, the intersection is given by $d$ disconnected, congruent "caps". This answer probably makes most sense in that case. I have not actually checked this in detail, let me know if I got this wrong.

An intuitive idea is to randomly pick one corner of the simplex (`w` below) and then randomly one point on the opposite face (`v` below) and then pick the convex combination of the two (`s*v+(1-s)*w` below) that has the right norm `c`. For the choice of `v` I now use `DirichletDistribution` which I learned about from [the answer of @JimB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/273640/85954) but note that I use it for a face of the simplex, not the simplex itself.

I have to warn that **the probability measure that I get is not the one OP expects**. Intuitively it is not extremely far away either, but this is a low dimensional intuition. It is possible that this code can be improved by picking `v` better. Here is the code:

```
randomsimplex[d_]:=RandomVariate[DirichletDistribution[
                      ConstantArray[1,d]]]//Join[#,{1-Total[#]}]&;
random[c_,d_]:=With[{i=RandomInteger[{1,d}]},
  With[{v=Insert[randomsimplex[d-1],0.,i],w=UnitVector[d,i]},
    With[{s=(1-c^2)/(1+Sqrt[c^2+(-1+c^2)*Dot[v,v]])},
      s*v+(1-s)*w]]];
```

Beware that for $c$ near the minimum it can happen that a complex solution is produced. But for $c \geq 1/\sqrt{2}$ this cannot happen. No resampling is used, and it also works in very high dimensions:

```
random[0.8,10000]
(* takes about 0.2 seconds *)
```

To check that it satisfies all conditions, one can use

```
test[c_,d_]:=With[{r=random[c,d]},
  And[Chop[Total[r]-1]===0,Chop[Norm[r]-c]===0,And@@Thread[r>=0]]];
```

For example

```
test[0.8,10000]
(* True *)
```

**Plot.** Here is a plot for $d=4$ and the threshold value $c=1/\sqrt{2}$. The plot is internal to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=1$, so the caps are 2-dimensional:

[image]

Code for the plot:

```
With[{X=Orthogonalize[Join[{{1,1,1,1}},IdentityMatrix[4][[1;;3]]]][[2;;4]]},
ListPointPlot3D[Table[random[1/Sqrt[2],4],10000].Transpose[X],BoxRatios->Automatic,Ticks->None]]
```

**Note.** The speed of this code is limited by `RandomVariate[DirichletDistribution[...]]`. To make it faster, generate many variates at once using  `RandomVariate[DirichletDistribution[...],n]`.

Comment: You are right about the "caps" as any permutation of the coordinates is equally likely.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion unnecessarily convoluted but still:

```
RandomPoint[
  ImplicitRegion[
   RegionMember[
    RegionIntersection[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .9], 
     Simplex[IdentityMatrix[3]]], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}], 1000] //
 Graphics3D[
   {Opacity[9/10], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .9], Simplex[IdentityMatrix[3]], 
    Point[#]},
   ViewPoint -> {1, 2, 1}] &
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the `ImplicitRegion` trick, I first assumed `RandomPoint` just didn't support intersections

Answer (score 0):

Some progress on an approach to address rejection sampling efficiency -- start at the "extreme point" (as much mass concentrated on one coordinate as possible), apply small random rotation, then project back onto the feasible region...repeat until the resulting distribution is close to isotropic (this part needs work)

```
randomRotate[v_, theta_] := (
   v2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], d];
   RotationMatrix[theta, {v, v2}] . v);
c = .8;
d = 3;
v = {xx, (1 - xx)/2, (1 - xx)/2};
v0 = v /. First@Solve[{Total[v*v] == c^2, 0 < xx < 1}, xx];
y = ConstantArray[1/d, d];
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];
projector = (ii - PseudoInverse[{y}] . {y});
planeProject[x_] := x . projector + y;
sphereProject[x_] := c*Normalize[x];

theta = Pi/40;
points = {};
v = v0;
For[i = 1, i < 100, i += 1,
  AppendTo[points, v];
  v = randomRotate[v, theta];
  AppendTo[points, v];
  v = Nest[sphereProject[planeProject[#]] &, v, 10];
  AppendTo[points, v];
  ];
```

[image]

Comment: "repeat until the result is `random enough`" ?  Are you suggesting that "random" is in the eye of the beholder?

Comment: "random enough" should be within some distance of isotropic distribution. If this were a standard MCMC, then there's some number of iterations for the distribution to be within eps of target distribution, aka the "burn-in period". Unclear what the burn in period is in this case, or even whether the resulting distribution is isotropic for any burn in

Comment: But more seriously is the rejection method that time consuming?  Using `n = 100000;
d = 100; x = RandomVariate[DirichletDistribution[ConstantArray[1, d]], n]; x = Join[#, {1 - Total[#]}] & /@ x; x1 = Select[x, # . # < 0.15^2 &];` takes 0.6 seconds (assuming that actually gets the kind of samples you want).

Comment: Oh, interesting, I assumed no rejection method can work for d=100, let me test your solution then

Comment: You'll find that for `c=0.8` that there are no rejections even with the sample size of 10,000.  That's why I used a smaller value of 0.15.

Comment: Ok, that's the issue, I need a method that works for c=0.8, currently I have a hole in my graphs because higher values of c are missing